# List comprehension for pandas: if column in pandas contains string, return a new column with string

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I am trying to move to a more pythonic way of writing my code e.g. list comprehension. Here, I am trying to create a new column 'Tag' that returns an element of a list if that element is contained in the Pandas column as per the dataframe news_df_output.

```
news = {'Text':['Nike invests in shoes', 'Adidas invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian']}
news_df = pd.DataFrame(news)
buyer = ['Amazon', "Adidas", 'Walmart', 'Children Place', 'Levi',  'VF']

# news_df['Tag'] = [x for x in buyer if news_df['Text'].str.contains(x) else 'n/a']

output_news = {'Text':['Nike invests in shoes', 'Adidas invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian'], 'Tag':['n/a', 'Adidas', 'n/a']}
news_df_output = pd.DataFrame(output_news)
news_df_output
```

However, my code returns an invalid syntax issue.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join of values of list by `|` for regex `or` and use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
news_df['Tag'] = news_df['Text'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(buyer) + ')')

print (news_df)
                         Text    Source     Tag
0       Nike invests in shoes       NYT     NaN
1  Adidas invests in t-shirts        WP  Adidas
2             dog drank water  Guardian     NaN
```

Your solution for all matches is possible change with another nested list comprehension:

```
news_df['Tag'] = [[y for y in buyer if y in x] for x in news_df['Text']]

print (news_df)
                         Text    Source       Tag
0       Nike invests in shoes       NYT        []
1  Adidas invests in t-shirts        WP  [Adidas]
2             dog drank water  Guardian        []
```

Or for first match use `next` with `iter` for possible set `NaN` if no match:

```
news_df['Tag'] = [next(iter([y for y in buyer if y in x]), np.nan) for x in news_df['Text']]
print (news_df)
                         Text    Source     Tag
0       Nike invests in shoes       NYT     NaN
1  Adidas invests in t-shirts        WP  Adidas
2             dog drank water  Guardian     NaN
```